# Prove $X$ and $Y$ with $X \sim \text{Unif}(0, 1)$ and $Y = X$ have no joint probability density function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, marginal-distribution, marginal-probability

Prove that the two random variables $X$ and $Y$ with $X \sim \text{Unif}(0, 1)$ and $Y = X$ have no joint probability density function (PDF), while each margin has a PDF.

Here is my progress, please help me grade it and complete the proof!

Note that if $B = \{ (x, y) \in  (0, 1) \times (0, 1) : x = y \}$, then $$1 = \underset{B}{\int\limits \int\limits} f_{X, Y}(x, y) = \int\limits_{x=0}^1 \quad \int\limits_{y=x}^x f_{X, Y}(x, y) = 0$$ a contradiction. Grade this solution, please. I do not have a clue how to do the second part.

Comment: You may want to state your working definition for "jointly continuous" and "continuous random variable." Also state your definition of $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ (it looks like you are assuming a joint PDF exists and then working for a contradiction, perhaps). The second part is trivial as you are told $X$ and $Y$ are both $Unif(0,1)$ which is a continuous CDF with a PDF.

Comment: @Michael I am guessing that the marginal PDFs are $1$ but how do I show that? My guess is that the integral is essentially $\int_0^1 1 dx$ or $dy$ but I do not get the reasoning behind where that $1$ is coming from since I only know how to compute marginal pdfs given that the joint PDF exists.

Comment: You are told that $X \sim Unif(0,1)$ so that means $X$ has PDF $$f_X(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc} 1 & \mbox{ if $0<x<1$} \\ 0 & \mbox{else} \end{array}\right.$$ The "marginal distribution" just means the distribution where $X$ is considered alone.

Comment: I downvoted this because it is clear the OP is asking us to help with his homework, and there isn't enough effort shown on the part of the OP. It would certainly be good if the OP were to at least write down the definition of a joint PDF, at least...

Comment: @Mike maybe not related to homework as he/she stated the problem incorrectly first.

Answer (score 1):

The joint cdf of $X$ and $Y$ are given below for any $(x, y) \in  (0, 1)^2$:

$$F_{X,Y}(x,y)=\mathbb P(X\le x,Y\le y)=P(X\le \min(x,y))= \min(x,y)$$

You can see that there is no $f_{X,Y}(u,w)$ such that for any $(x, y) \in  (0, 1)^2$ the following representation holds:

$$F_{X,Y}(x,y)=\int\limits_{u=0}^x \quad \int\limits_{w=0}^y f_{X, Y}(u, w) \text{d}u\text{d}w.$$

Indeed, if such a function exits, then it (almost everywhere) satisfies

$$f_{X, Y}(x, y)=\frac{\partial^2{F_{X, Y}(x, y)}}{\partial{x}\partial{y}},$$

but the RHS is zero on non-diagonal points $(x,y)$ with $x \ne y$ and not defined on diagonal $(x,x)$ points. Hence, for a zero function $f_{X,Y}(u,w)=0$ , the above integral representation cannot be given.

In fact, $X$ and $Y$ have a continuous distribution, without a joint density function, while its margins have density functions.